# How to put Hard Block on Bluetooth and WiFi?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I have an Asus laptop with Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter. I've installed Ubuntu 13.04. 
I tried `sudo rfkill block all` and the output of `rfkill list all` is

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Is there any way to put hard block on both WiFi and Bluetooth?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear you want to block wifi and bluetooth so they do not work?

Comment: I want to do that for the sake of power consumption. But in a way that whenever I need WiFi and Bluetooth, I could remove them from block list.

Comment: Hard blocks are done by the physical switch on your computer being turned off, if it is not a switch on your system then it is controlled by a key combination for example FN key + f5. We might could write a script but then you would have to enter commands to turn wifi and bluetooth on. Wifi has power management built in automatically to save power when running on battery unless you have deactivated it. You can check with `iwconfig`

Comment: Did that give you the results you want?

Comment: Would you mind telling me why I can't turn Bluetooth on until I restart my laptop?!

Comment: I am not sure, if you find my answer useful for turning off wifi and bluetooth please click accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard blocks are done by the physical switch on your computer being turned off, if it is not a switch on your system then it is controlled by a key combination for example FN key + f5. We might could write a script but then you would have to enter commands to turn wifi and bluetooth on. Wifi has power management built in automatically to save power when running on battery unless you have deactivated it. You can check with iwconfig

Comment: I understand your comment. That is clear. But I'm not able to turn Bluetooth on. I've tried different commands But No one work! There is only one way! I must restart my laptop after switching on by Fn + F2.

Comment: You can try `sudo modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1`